# jQuery Datepicker (Keith Wood) prevent closing when date is selected

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I prevent the closing of the datepicker when I click on a date. 
Is there an option for that? I am using [Keith Wood's Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) v4.0.6.
I want to close it by clicking the "Close" link.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by hacking the code. I know it's not good to do it like this, but it works.

Comment the line:

```
this.hide(target);
```

it's on row 1700 in the function selectDate.

Tested on Firefox 17, IE 10, Chrome 23.